# Is there any way to link together 2 time frame nodes in with animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

For anyone who sees this and has managed to get their hands on Animation Nodes, is there any way to combine 2 time frame nodes?
To elaborate, I want to record the transformed movement and rotation of a cube. Every time I use 1 time frame node, all sockets connected, it keeps recording the same frame, even with "always" turned off. Instead, I have tried to connect 2 time frame nodes to any combine vector. it failed, only 1 at a time. I have tried to node search a "combine time frame" or something, no dice. Is there any way to record 2 separate locations and rotations in 2 separate frames

Comment: Can you maybe make an image to show what you want to do?
Maybe you just have to uncheck "Use Current Transforms" in the advanced node settings of the Object Transforms Input node? You find these settings in the right toolbar in the node editor.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LPYLZ

Whenever I attempt to use an object transform to record the location and rotation of an object, everything is fine, but whenever I attempt to record what happens from 1 frame the end frame, it refuses to let both connect. This is even worse when the location and rotation runs incorrectly when I connect a time info node to begin with.

I am attempting to connect 2 separate time info nodes, 1 for the starting frame, 1 for the end frame. Neither are allowed to be connected to the same socket, though.

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do. What means record? You want to read the obj transform at certain frame or you try to set the transformation?

Comment: Frame 1 must have 1 location and rotation. The final frame, frame 50, must have a different location and rotation. All frames in-between must display a smooth transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Time** submenu you also have some **Animate ... nodes** for vector, euler etc.
You should use them for animating between a frame and another.

Note that:

- they also have a Time output so that you can use several in a series
- they have an interpolation method. There is a whole interpolation submenu for having a lot of control over that, if the default set of options is not enough.

[image]

ps:
For complex situations or for many objects or instances of an object, if more than several animate nodes would be used, use subprograms, loops especially for lists of objects, having animate nodes triggered by various rules.

Comment: ...IT WORKS! YEEEEES! THANK YOU!!!!!

I used the node setup in the screen shot! EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED! THANK YOU!!!